# An integral average condition and its relationship with BMO, VMO, and Sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $V: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a vector field which satisfies
$$
\lim_{l \to \infty} \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n} \left|\frac{1}{l^n} \int_{[0,l]^n}V(x+y) dy \right| = 0
$$
What is the relationship between this integral condition and more well-known conditions? Is such a vector field in BMO, VMO, any $L^p$ or Sobolev space?

Does the answer to any of the above change if we additionally assume $V \in L^\infty$?

Comment: All of the above spaces impose local requirements on your functions which your condition doesn't include.

Comment: @ChristianRemling What do you mean?